# MS Access with SQL Server back-end update fails without error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, sql-update, sqldatatypes

This simple VBA statement does not work as expected:

```
strSQl = "UPDATE Inventory SET NumberOfBlocks = BlocksReserved, LastUser = 'Me' WHERE InventoryID = 1234;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQl, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges
```

LastUser is updated, but NumberOfBlocks remains unchanged, no error.

If I run this statement in SSMS or as an Access query, it works.

If I use a variable in the VBA statement ..."SET NumberOfBlocks = " & intBlocksReserved & ",..., it works.

Constant works: ..."SET NumberOfBlocks = 555"...

**And this one works, too**: NumberOfBlocks = (BlocksReserved * 1)

NumberOfBlocks and BlocksReserved are both smallint and not null; the record has a timestamp/rowversion field.

Environment: Access 2016 with SQL 2016 back-end.

Any ideas why my initial statement fails silently? Thanks!

---

More testing confirms my previous findings:

1. Created a new Access db, table Inventory: ID (AutoNumber, PK), NumberOfBlocks (Integer), BlocksReserved (Integer), LastUser (Short Text 10)
2. Created a table in SQL Server:

   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [NumberOfBlocks] [smallint] NULL,
   [BlocksReserved] [smallint] NULL,
   [LastUser] nvarchar NULL,
   [RV] [timestamp] NOT NULL
3. Set ID as Primary Key, linked SQL table, entered test data in both.
4. Run exactly the same code on both tables (only changed the table name):

   Dim strSQl As String

   strSQl = "UPDATE Inventory SET NumberOfBlocks = BlocksReserved, LastUser = 'Me';"
   CurrentDb.Execute strSQl, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

Result:

Local Access table: NumberOfBlocks = BlocksReserved, LastUser = 'Me'

Linked SQL table: NumberOfBlocks unchanged, LastUser = 'Me'

---

More notes:

- Changing the datatype in SQL Server to int (instead of smallint) did not make a difference.
- However, explicitly converting the field worked:

  ...SET NumberOfBlocks = CInt(BlocksReserved)...
- just as

  ...SET NumberOfBlocks = (BlocksReserved * 1)...

I guess, that turns my post from a question to a heads-up...

Comment: Fails silently because CurrentDb.Execute is designed with that behavior. Why would you update a field with same data of another field in same table?

Comment: There are more fields in this record. I had to split the original record, i.e. I first inserted a record with the remaining available inventory quantity, which leaves the original record as completely reserved for that order number, i.e. it allows us to later change or cancel that order.

Comment: Why are you saving 'remaining available inventory quantity'? Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: The business logic behind it is a bit complicated and maybe I didn't explain it well - sorry! But my question is purely technical: why does "SET NumberOfBlocks = BlocksReserved" fail while "SET NumberOfBlocks = 50" or SET NumberOfBlocks = (BlocksReserved * 1)" works.

Comment: I tested an UPDATE that I think replicates your structure and field is updated just fine. Edited question to provide sample data.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help June7. I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: I would check the data type of blocksreserved. A constant works but check what the data type of that column is. It is likely a different data type then the column NumberofBlocks. Perahps the value is too large, or some other issue. So check the actual value of blockReserved. It would seem that the value in that column can't fit into NumberOfBlocks.

Comment: Since others seem to ignore the details that you already shared (i.e. it is obvious to me that you've already checked datatypes, etc.), I'll be adventurous and blame Access.  Since it is not executing this as a pass-through, then Access is necessarily analyzing and reconstructing the query before sending to SQL Server.  Sorry I'm not familiar with SQL Server, but I'm aware that you should be able to observe what queries are passed to the server from Access. I'd suspect that SQL Server is not receiving the same query.  This doesn't explain why it is happening, but places the cause with Access.

Comment: What if you change the order of the set statements... `UPDATE Inventory SET LastUser = 'Me', NumberOfBlocks = BlocksReserved WHERE InventoryID = 1234;` I have observed many times perfectly good queries that did not work, but simply changing the order of columns would fix the problems.

Comment: I did some more testing which confirmed my initial findings. The execute statement works fine on an Access table but fails on a SQL Server table, unless the value to be assigned (BlocksReserved) is directly or indirectly converted into a numerical value. Details in the updated posting above.
Thanks for your time and input June7, Albert Kallal and C.Perkins :-)

Comment: I share the analysis of @CPerkins. If you go in design mode on your linked table, what datatype do you see for your 2 columns `NumberOfBlocks` and `BlocksReserved` ? If you notice a slight difference you might have an indication of what's going on. It should not happen though, especially with SQL server tables, and it is probably another bug. As a rule of thumb : avoid  updating linked tables that arent MS Access. Prefer pass-through queries.

Comment: @rkraft  You can post your test results as an answer.  Perhaps it does not explain the deep workings of the Access "bug", but it is still an answer.  Then at least your "heads up" can have its due credit on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further tests confirmed that this is a bug in the **Execute command** under the following conditions:

- It's an UPDATE statement where one integer field is assigned to another one, such as *SET FieldA = FieldB* (same numeric datatype)
- It's a linked table in SQL Server.

The same SQL statement will work fine

- with a table in Access or
- when used in a query.

Tested work-arounds:

- Explicitly convert the field: SET FieldA = CInt(FieldB)... (or CLng...)
- Use any calculation: SET FieldA = FieldB * 1
- Use a variable: SET FieldA = " & intFieldB

Answer (score 1):

This is quite interesting. I can reproduce it with Access 2010, SQL Server 2008 R2, ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

But **only** if the (N)VARCHAR column is included in the `UPDATE` query!
`UPDATE AAA SET Smallint2 = Smallint1, Int2 = Int1;` works.

```sql
CREATE TABLE AAA (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    Smallint1 SMALLINT NULL, 
    Smallint2 SMALLINT NULL, 
    Int1 INT NULL,
    Int2 INT NULL,
    foo NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
    RV TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_AAA PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
GO

INSERT AAA (Smallint1, Smallint2, Int1, Int2, foo) 
VALUES (1, 0, 77, 9999, 'asdf'), 
       (3456, NULL, NULL, 1234, 'null')
```

Access-VBA:

```vb
Sub TestAAA()

    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "UPDATE AAA SET Smallint2 = Smallint1, Int2 = Int1;"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

    Stop
    ' Requery table => UPDATE was successful!

    ' Edit and save values in Smallint1 / Int1

    strSql = "UPDATE AAA SET Smallint2 = Smallint1, Int2 = Int1, foo = 'with NVARCHAR';"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

    Stop
    ' Requery => Smallint2 / Int2 are not updated, "foo" is!

    strSql = "UPDATE AAA SET Smallint2 = CInt(Smallint1), Int2 = CLng(Int1), foo = 'with Conversion';"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

    ' Requery => Smallint2 / Int2 are updated!

End Sub
```

Results:

- initial state
- after first update
- after manual edit and second update
- after third update

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| ID | Smallint1 | Smallint2 |   Int1    |   Int2    |       foo       |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1         | 0         | 77        | 9999      | asdf            |
| 2  | 3456      |           |           | 1234      | null            |
|    |           |           |           |           |                 |
| ID | Smallint1 | Smallint2 | Int1      | Int2      | foo             |
| 1  | 1         | 1         | 77        | 77        | asdf            |
| 2  | 3456      | 3456      |           |           | null            |
|    |           |           |           |           |                 |
| ID | Smallint1 | Smallint2 | Int1      | Int2      | foo             |
| 1  | 222       | 1         | 988888888 | 77        | with NVARCHAR   |
| 2  | 333       | 3456      | 999999999 |           | with NVARCHAR   |
|    |           |           |           |           |                 |
| ID | Smallint1 | Smallint2 | Int1      | Int2      | foo             |
| 1  | 222       | 222       | 988888888 | 988888888 | with Conversion |
| 2  | 333       | 333       | 999999999 | 999999999 | with Conversion |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I can confirm your observation in Access 2016 (365) with SQL Server 2016 Developer: without the nvarchar field as part of the update, conversion is not needed.